# Javascript and function using 'this'

Tags: javascript

I'm quite new in object creation in Javascript with the use of "this", bind and event. Trying to mastering those things which are new for me in a common use.
I did a simple test in Javascript, creating a function that can be called by any html element to apply a css class after a moment with a setTimeout function :

HTML :

```
<body>
  <div id="circle"></div>
  <div id="square"></div>
  <div id="triangle"></div>
</body>
```

CSS :

```
.square {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all ease 1s;
}

.rotate {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

JS ( i assigned the keyword "this" to a value called self to not refer to the window object) :

```
var square = document.getElementById('square');
square.classList.add('square');

function rotate (elm){
  elm.classList.toggle('rotate');
}

square.addEventListener('click', function(){
  var self = this;
  setTimeout(function(){
   rotate(self);
  }, 500);
});
```

I did it in another way like that :

```
function rotate(){
  this.classList.toggle('rotate');
  console.log(this.getAttribute('id'));
}

square.addEventListener('click', rotate);
```

Above with the event listener, the keyword "this" is naturally passed to the function and the getAttribute returns the
good id of the div where i click : "square".

//

**Those two exemples works but i want to know if there is a better way to do a function like that using "this" in the function.** A kind of mix of the two ways i showed you above. Also want to add the setTimeout function but i don't know how. For exemple if i do something like that, the this keyword is undefined and the syntax of the add event listener seems wrong :

```
function rotate(){
  this.classList.toggle('rotate');
  console.log(this.getAttribute('id'));
}
square.addEventListener('click', rotate(){
  setTimeout(function(){
   rotate();
  }, 500);
});
```

Can you show me a better way to achieve that?

Comment: Have you looked into arrow functions?

Comment: `square.addEventListener('click', function(){ setTimeout(rotate, 500, this); })`

Comment: @m_callens i didn't looked into arrow functions but i will take a look on it. Thanks.

Comment: @Bergi your proposition is better than what i've tried to do. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

```js
var square = document.getElementById('square');
square.classList.add('square');

function rotate() {
  this.classList.toggle('rotate');
}

square.addEventListener('click', function() {
  setTimeout(rotate.bind(this), 500);
});
```

```css
.square {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all ease 1s;
}

.rotate {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="circle"></div>
<div id="square"></div>
<div id="triangle"></div>
```

Comment: It's what i was looking for. Using bind() to achieve that. Thanks!